# Vertical table with dynamic headings and dynamic values in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table, angular7

Consider my scenario, I have 2 lists coming from the service call, one list will be used as the table headings and another list will be used as the table data.
Something like this---

List 1 - [Name, Age]

List 2 - [Shubham, 25]

Table should look like -

```
Name    Shubham
Age     25
```

Another example...

List 1 - [DOC1, DOC2]

List 2 - [Pending, Approved]

```
DOC1    Pending
DOC2    Approved
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: show the lists.

Comment: I have shared the lists in the description.

Consider List 1 - {DOC1, DOC2}
            & List 2 - {Pending, Approved}

Added another example in the question

Comment: Lists are array, you have shown objects

Comment: updated, can you help now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ms7kdr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<table>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of list1;let i = index">
        <tr>
            <td> {{list1[i]}}</td>
            <td> {{list2[i]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

Comment: I feel so dumb right now, I was doing the exact same thing and had list1[i] in the second <td> as well, and was repeatedly asking myself just one question- "Why the hell am I getting same items in both the <td>'s?"
May be I need to rest a little. 
Still, I am very thankful to you & a lot disappointed in myself.

Comment: We all make silly mistakes. Please upvote and accept the answer if it was useful :)